# PWM in raspberry with L293D

Tags: pwm

maybe this ask is repeated but i need solve this special situation, i have an arm robot with 3 Freedon deegre, i want to control position of each motor with a raspberry pi 2 and L293D like a motor driver,  i am source with 3.3 logic and 6 v source,but i don't know how to manipulate the PWM to change the action velocity like in arduino that only change the cycle(0-255) you have different velocity, thank

Comment: Ah, let me see.  L293D is similar to L298N.  You can search L298N and found a couple of questions with answers also helpful to L293D.

Comment: yes, but my question is how modulate the frenquence to change the velocity

Comment: Well, you may also like to search for "PWM" controlling  "servo".  PWM controling L298N DC motors is basically the same, once you know how to do PWM.

Comment: If you are using I2C 3DOF MEMS, you might also like to search for "PCA9685", an I2C PWM module for controlling LED and servo alike.

Answer (score 1):

You do not modulate the PWM frequency to change motor speed.

You change the PWM dutycycle.

You set a dutycycle of 0% for off, 100% for fully on, 50% for half on, etc.

If the permitted dutycycle range is 0 to 255 that would be 0 (0%), 255 (100%), and 128 (50%).

If this isn't what you are asking you need to clarify your question.

Comment: only (%), so i can use 55 %,63% etc?